# Rails: Joining with where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails development and have run into an issue with joins and merges.

I have two models: Instructor and Session.  I would like to display all instructors who have a session in the future (i.e. don't show instructors who are not scheduled to teach anything) along with a list of those sessions.  Here's what I have, but it's not quite right (This shows instructors with more than 1 session in the future multiple times):

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :instructor

    def self.is_current
        where(start_time: Time.now.beginning_of_day..(Time.now.beginning_of_day + 1.year))
    end
end

class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sessions

    def self.with_current_sessions
        joins(:sessions).merge(Session.is_current)
    end
end

class InstructorsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @instructors = Instructor.with_current_sessions
    end
end
```

And then the instructors index view:

```
<% @instructors.each do |inst| %>
    <h3><%= inst.full_name %></h3>
    <% if inst.sessions.size > 0 %><p>Teaching <%= pluralize(inst.sessions.size, 'workshop') %>:</p>
        <ul class="standard">
            <% inst.sessions.each do |sess| %>
                <li><%= link_to sess.name, sess %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So what is not working exactly? Also I think Session is not a good name for a model, as it can be associates with a lot of Rails and otherwise keywords.

Comment: Instructors with more than one session show up more than once. And all sessions show up in the listing, not just the future ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a defalut scope to my Session model (which I also renamed to Workshop):

```
default_scope { where(start_time: Time.now.beginning_of_day..(Time.now.beginning_of_day + 1.year)) }
```

To show all sessions (including past ones):

```
@workshops = Workshop.unscoped
```

No need for merges anymore.